# Connecting to MS SQL from PHP on IIS using PEAR MDB2

Tags: php, sql-server, iis, pear, mdb2

Sorry to have to ask this here; php.net just seems to be full of exceptions and excuses regarding this.

I'm running IIS 6.0 with PHP 5.3.6. I've got MDB2 installed and working (even with a custom-written driver for an off-brand RDBMS). That's all working great. But now I need to have PHP connect to a bit of standard technology: MS SQL.

The problem is the mssql driver for MDB2 requires PHP to have been compiled with [special flags](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.installation.php). Hard to do with php binaries :).

I could go down the road of getting a compiler, downloading the source and recompiling, but I'm just starting to wonder if I'm out in the weeds when there's actually a better, more standard way of getting the job done.

So, my question is: For IIS 6 + PHP 5.3.6, is there a different, easier, more commonly-tread route to connecting to MS SQL?

Comment: Have a look at my answer, it's fairly fool proof.

Comment: Good info. You mention in your answer "if you loaded the PDO driver..."  Is there another method/extension these drivers work with other than PDO; maybe even MDB2 perhaps?

Comment: Also, if you'll put your comment in an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: My apologies for not quite getting the PEAR MDB2 bit about this question, I shouldn't have closed this as a duplicate. I've added an answer which should help.

Comment: It would be great if you could contribute your custom driver to PEAR - assuming it's ok to do so.

Comment: Agreed, they seem to be fairly open to adding new drivers. I believe the MS SQL native driver started off as a drive-by issue logged in the bug tracker by some bod.

Comment: If the company I developed the driver for gives permission, I'll do so. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've rightly pointed out, support for the community `mssql` driver is not compiled into the latest Windows PHP binaries.

Presently the current stable release of MDB2 (2.4.1) does not support the official Microsoft `sqlsrv` native driver.

However if you're willing to live on the edge a bit with the beta release of MDB2 then all is not lost. There is a Microsoft native `sqlsrv` driver that is part of the 2.5.0b3 release:

> http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2_Driver_sqlsrv

First of all ensure that you've installed the Microsoft native driver as I described in my answer here:

> [Connection between MSSQL and PHP 5.3.5 on IIS is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5425322/connection-between-mssql-and-php-5-3-5-on-iis-is-not-working/5432118#5432118)

Then to install the PEAR MDB2 sqlsrv driver do the following:

1. If you've already installed MDB2 then uninstall it:

   `pear uninstall mdb2`

   If you already have any drivers installed then you'll need to uninstall these first:

   `pear uninstall mdb2#mysql`
2. Next tell PEAR that you want to allow non-stable beta packages:

   `pear config-set preferred_state beta`
3. Install `MDB2_Driver_sqlsrv`

   `pear install MDB2_Driver_sqlsrv`

   This will install the latest MDB2 beta and the MS sqlsrv driver:

   ```
   downloading MDB2_Driver_sqlsrv-1.5.0b3.tgz ...
   Starting to download MDB2_Driver_sqlsrv-1.5.0b3.tgz (29,468 bytes)
   .........done: 29,468 bytes
   downloading MDB2-2.5.0b3.tgz ...
   Starting to download MDB2-2.5.0b3.tgz (130,865 bytes)
   ...done: 130,865 bytes
   install ok: channel://pear.php.net/MDB2_Driver_sqlsrv-1.5.0b3
   install ok: channel://pear.php.net/MDB2-2.5.0b3
   MDB2: Optional feature fbsql available (Frontbase SQL driver for MDB2)
   MDB2: Optional feature ibase available (Interbase/Firebird driver for MDB2)
   MDB2: Optional feature mssql available (MS SQL Server driver for MDB2)
   MDB2: Optional feature mysql available (MySQL driver for MDB2)
   MDB2: Optional feature mysqli available (MySQLi driver for MDB2)
   MDB2: Optional feature oci8 available (Oracle driver for MDB2)
   MDB2: Optional feature odbc available (ODBC driver for MDB2)
   MDB2: Optional feature pgsql available (PostgreSQL driver for MDB2)
   MDB2: Optional feature querysim available (Querysim driver for MDB2)
   MDB2: Optional feature sqlite available (SQLite2 driver for MDB2)
   MDB2: Optional feature sqlsrv available (MS SQL Server driver for MDB2)
   MDB2: To install optional features use "pear install pear/MDB2#featurename"
   ```
4. It's probably advisable to knock PEAR back to only allowing stable packages again

   `pear config-set preferred_state stable`

I just tried this with the following test script and I was able to connect to my local MS SQL Server and retrieve some data:

```
<?php
require_once 'MDB2.php';

$dsn = array(
    'phptype'  => 'sqlsrv',
    'username' => 'test',
    'password' => 'testpass',
    'hostspec' => 'localhost',
    'database' => 'PEARMDBTEST',
);

$mdb2 =& MDB2::connect($dsn);

if(PEAR::isError($mdb2)) 
{
    die($mdb2->getMessage());
}

$res =& $mdb2->query('SELECT * FROM TestData');

while (($row = $res->fetchRow())) {
    echo $row['TestDataRow'] . "<br/>";
}

?>
```

Comment: I'm getting strict standards warnings, any idea? `Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in E:\Websites\Dev\mdb2_test.php on line 16'`

Comment: @TonyM - just hide them by adjusting your error reporting, not ideal but sometimes it's the only way. Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9984309/419  covers all the bases based on what type of access you have to the server.

Comment: @TonyM also tacking on a `& ~E_DEPRECATED` doesn't hurt. Kinda depends on what version of PHP you're using.

Comment: @TonyM ...and finally see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11777908/419  might be related, but would need to see what line 16 in your script  looks like.

Answer (score 1):

MS provides a PHP driver for MSSQL: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20098