# CMS Made Simple Strict Standards Error

Tags: php, content-management-system, smarty, cmsmadesimple

I look after a few older sites using CMS Made Simple version 1.4.  Recently they've all started showing strict standards errors as below.  Has something changed recently on servers that could be causing this?

> Strict Standards: Declaration of Captcha::GetHelp() should be
>   compatible with CMSModule::GetHelp($lang = 'en_US') in
>   /home/alliance/public_html/modules/Captcha/lib/classes/module/class.captcha.php
>   on line 1071

Comment: possible duplicate of [Disabling Strict Standards in PHP 5.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983286/disabling-strict-standards-in-php-5-4)

Comment: most likely PHP has been upgraded to 5.4 (see the link above)

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for you help, that was it exactly.  I've hidden the error messages for now until I can find a better fix.