# Strict Standards: Non-static method DOMDocument::load() rss feed

Tags: php, rss, joomla3.0, rss-reader

I'm getting this error from several RSS feed joomla modules. (below is an example from one of them, LightRSSFeedReader, but I'm getting the issue on the others I have tried)

```
Strict Standards: Non-static method DOMDocument::load() should not be called statically in /mnt/data/vhosts/casite-395567.cloudaccess.net/httpdocs/modules/mod_LightRSSFeedReader/tmpl/default.php on line 40

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /mnt/data/vhosts/casite-395567.cloudaccess.net/httpdocs/modules/mod_LightRSSFeedReader/tmpl/default.php on line 48
```

Line 40 reads: `$rss = DOMDocument::load("$rss_feed_url");`

There is some discussion on the web to use "->" instead of "::" but simply changing it (in an override of course), but that just creates more errors.

There is also something about getting the right code from http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php but I'm at a loss as to how that plays with the "$rss" variable.

As you can tell, I'm not a PHP coder.

Any help is widely appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like LightRSSFeedReader was carelessly developed without E_STRICT under account.  Newer versions of PHP include strict warnings in the E_ALL error reporting setting, which is likely why this was never a problem for them.

Comment: It is probably fixable by declaring the object, then calling `load()` on it as in `$dom = new DOMDocument(); $rss = $dom->load($rss_feed_url);`

Comment: If your 3rd party code is throwing a lot of `E_STRICT` warnings, you may just need to lower the error reporting threshold to exclude them http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983286/disabling-strict-standards-in-php-5-4, as it is impractical to fix.

Comment: Thanks. I will try disabling the E_Strict warnings first, as that seems simple enough....and it worked! But I will try with your first solution after the site launch. Thanks again.

Comment: is your problem solved now? If the answer is correct, you might consider accepting the answer...

Answer (score 5):

There is an example on the exact page you are referring to:

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load('book.xml');
echo $doc->saveXML();
?>
```

you can only call the "load" method on an instance; so you first need to create a `DOMDocument` instant, and then apply load on it.

In short, as @MichaelBerkowski proposed: use

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$rss = $dom->load($rss_feed_url);
```

Comment: What I find unusual - the [`DOMDocument::load()` docs](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php) actually suggest calling it statically, with a warning. _This method may be called statically, but will issue an E_STRICT error._  That suggestion should go away in the PHP 5.4+ era where `E_STRICT` is more commonly adhered to.