# Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference PHP 5.4

Tags: php, reference, porting

I upgraded my PHP version to 5.4 ([XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) 1.7.3 to 1.8.0). Now I see *Strict Standards* error, for `myDBconnection`:

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in C:\xampp\htdocs\alous\include\dbconn.php on line 4

#### dbconn.php:

```
<?php
    defined('_VALID') or die('Restricted Access!');

    $conn = &ADONewConnection($config['db_type']); // <--- This Line 4

    if ( !$conn->Connect($config['db_host'],
                         $config['db_user'],
                         $config['db_pass'],
                         $config['db_name'])) {

        echo 'Could not connect to MySQL! Please check your database settings!';
        die();
    }
    $conn->execute("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
?>
```

*Note:* I don't need to disable Strict Standards in php.ini with this method `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT`! I want to fix my PHP code.

Comment: Does the warning disappear if you modify line 4 to `$conn = ADONewConnection($config['db_type']);`

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You should remove the `&` (ampersand) symbol, so that line 4 will look like this:

```
$conn = ADONewConnection($config['db_type']);
```

This is because ADONewConnection already returns an object by reference. As per [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php), assigning the result of a reference to object by reference results in an E_DEPRECATED message as of PHP 5.3.0

Comment: He's not using `new` though.

Comment: Yes, `&` should be removed in this instance, but not for the reason give (as @sam suggests). It's simply that the result of the assignment is not a _variable_, which results in an E_STRICT message, not an E_DEPRECATED warning, which is what happens with the `new` operator. In fact, using `=&` could actually be valid if the `ADONewConnection()` _function_ is set to [return a reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php).

Comment: Can you add the reason why it should be removed (by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11778004/edit) - not here in comments)?

Answer (score 10):

It's because you're trying to assign an object by reference. Remove the ampersand and your script should work as intended.