# Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in ADONewConnection

Tags: php, postgresql, ado

My server setup is

```
PHP 5.5.8
PostgreSQL 9.3
adodb 5
```

Here are the coorrisponding lines to error

```
45 include($GLOBALS["webpath"] . "/adodb5/adodb.inc.php");
46 $conn = &ADONewConnection('postgres');
47 $conn->PConnect('host=www.site.com port=5432 dbname=database user=username password=secret');
```

Have Also tried

```
$conn = &ADONewConnection('postgres9');
```

but i receve this error message everytime i try to run this page

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/site/public_html/cron.php on line 46
```

Comment: This was two questions in one. I've removed the second unrelated one; please post a new question for that. You can see your text in the edit history. Also fixed your tags.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference PHP 5.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777908/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-assigned-by-reference-php-5-4)

Answer (score 1):

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in ADONewConnection

```
$conn = &ADONewConnection('postgres9');
```

You need to remove the `&` prefix.

The `&` prefix attempts to [assign a reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php#language.operators.assignment.reference) to the *return value of the function*, to `$conn`. So that `$conn` refers to the very same object and not a *copy* of that object. This was necessary in PHP4, however, a change in the way class instances are stored in PHP5 makes this unnecessary.

Just to slightly confuse matters, this would actually be valid in PHP5 if the function [returned a reference](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php). But it doesn't in this instance, hence the strict notice. Normally, "only variables can be assigned by reference".