# WordPress : Only variables should be assigned by reference

Tags: wordpress

I am use this way to get images in post like :

```
$images =& get_children( 'post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent='.get_the_ID() );
```

Its work good but show me this error in console :
Only variables should be assigned by reference

How can solved it ?

Comment: Did you try : `$images = get_children( 'post_type=attachment&post_mime_type=image&post_parent='.get_the_ID() );` ?

Comment: You can pass by reference variables, new statements or references returned from functions. Read more [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php). Just remove `&` and you'll get array in `$images` variable that you'll be able to use.

Comment: yes its work ,,, thankx

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11777908/6521116

Answer (score 0):

The error is from the PHP configuration behind wordpress enforcing E_STRICT rules. 
You can only return variables by reference from a function - nothing else.

For more on how to alter your php.ini file (hides the warning but does not fix the cause)
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migrating5.errorrep.php

More here including examples of what (I think) you are doing here - 
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.references.return.php
.