# PHP error - Only variables should be assigned by reference

Tags: php, function, variables, reference

I am receiving a PHP error on my site since the PHP version updated. The message I am getting is:

> Only variables should be assigned by reference.

The code in question this is referring to is

```
        $this->_base_classes =& is_loaded();
```

What do I need to change to correct the error?
Thanks.

Comment: `=&` is specifically for assigning variables by reference. Your error is stating that `$this->_base_classes` is not a variable. You'll need to state what `$this` actually is to allow us to provide any more information.

Comment: You can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11777908/6521116)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying use reference on function. Remove the `&` will be ok.  Here is the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatare.php). You can also refer to the [**comment** of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11778004/6521116).

> References in PHP are a means to access the same variable content by
>   different names. They are not like C pointers; for instance, you
>   cannot perform pointer arithmetic using them, they are not actual
>   memory addresses, and so on. See [What References Are Not](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.arent.php) for more
>   information. Instead, they are symbol table aliases. Note that in PHP,
>   variable name and variable content are different, so the same content
>   can have different names. The closest analogy is with Unix filenames
>   and files - variable names are directory entries, while variable
>   content is the file itself. References can be likened to hardlinking
>   in Unix filesystem.

Comment: Thanks. I did remove the & and now I just get a HTTP 500 error on the page. Not sure what else I need to do.

Comment: @user3612498 now, you need to check php error.log to understand the cause of 500 error

Comment: then you should see the server log, check the issue

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you should also check your PHP version. I encountered the same issue but  downgraded PHP to a lower version.