# How to fix the PHP new version script error?

Tags: php

I recently updated PHP version of my PHPlinkdirectory to latest version, but after updating it I started getting following error. I instantly changed the new version to the old but the error still exits.

The PHP is running on version 5.4.

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be assigned by reference in /home/domain/public_html/init.php on line 275

Strict Standards: Non-static method SmartyPaginate::connect() should not be called statically in /home/domain/public_html/index.php on line 688

Strict Standards: Non-static method SmartyPaginate::getTotal() should not be called statically in /home/domain/public_html/libs/smarty/SmartyPaginate.class.php on line 51

Strict Standards: Non-static method SmartyPaginate::getUrlVar() should not be called statically in /home/domain/public_html/libs/smarty/SmartyPaginate.class.php on line 52

Strict Standards: Non-static method SmartyPaginate::disconnect() should not be called statically in /home/domain/public_html/index.php on line 693

Strict Standards: Non-static method SmartyPaginate::reset() should not be called statically in /home/domain/public_html/index.php on line 694

Strict Standards: Non-static method SmartyPaginate::setPrevText() should not be called statically in /home/domain/public_html/index.php on line 696

Strict Standards: Non-static method SmartyPaginate::setNextText() should not be called statically in /home/domain/public_html/index.php on line 697
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777908/strict-standards-only-variables-should-be-assigned-by-reference-php-5-4

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4684454/error-message-strict-standards-non-static-method-should-not-be-called-staticall Please do some basic research before asking.

Comment: Where's your code bud? Can't help too much without seeing the actual code

Comment: @misorude. I tried that but it didn't solved the problem.

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs Plz let me know which code you you exactly needed as I am not aware about the actual file.

Comment: You tried what exactly? Be specific.

Comment: your error message shows you which file is trying to call the code - start there

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not about PHP version. You are calling a normal function like it is static but it is not.

You can try to way in here:

```
public static function connect() {

}
```

or you can call function like this:

```
$paginate = new SmartyPaginate;
$paginate->connect();
$paginate->getTotal();
```

Comment: you can call a method that's not static using `::` e.g. (`parent::method`) - problem may be elsewhere .. hard to be definitive without seeing code