# Connect to MS SQL Server 2008 with PHP running on XP / IIS

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, iis

I'm trying to connect to MSSQL 2008 from a (LAN) XP machine running IIS 5.1 & PHP 5.3.

I tried following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/5432118

Problems started when I had no `snapshot.txt`, however as I am running IIS and PHP as FastCGI extension I am fairly confident I need the non-threadsafe dll ?

Anyway, I downloaded `SQLSRV30.EXE` and extracted `php_sqlsrv_53_nts.dll` to my `ext` dir and added the extension to my `php.ini`. I also confirmed the `extension_dir` was correct & installed Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Native Client before restarting IIS.

Unfortunately `phpinfo()` does not list sqlsrv as a loaded extension and I am now totally lost so any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you remember to bounce any running `php-cgi.exe` processes in task manager (`IISRESET` should do this if you're on a non-production box). If you don't, FastCGI will pass requests to any already warmed up `php-cgi.exe` processes which won't have re-read your `php.ini` file after you make any changes.

Comment: Another thing to try is to run `php.exe -i` from the command line and have a look at the output (it'll output a text based version of `phpinfo()` without all the HTML markup). Would be helpful if you could do a `php.exe -i > info.txt` and paste this to a pastebin.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/E2sddmyS - thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I eventually got the the bottom of it so I thought I'd report back and hopefully save some else a head ache....

In my `php.ini` I set `display_startup_errors = On`, restarted IIS and reloaded the page. At this point I got the magic nugget of information that for some reason was not being added to the log `Fatal error: Unable to load Library........error: Access is denied`.

So I navigated to the `ext` dir and selected the extension

```
Right Click > Properties > Security
```

And added permissions for `Users` & `Power Users` - restarted IIS and boom sqlsrv was loaded.