# Install SQLSRV driver on Linux, or other UTF-8 capable driver?

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, utf-8, sqlsrv

SQLSRV is the only driver for PHP that is capable of storing *UTF-8* strings into two-byte columns (`NVARCHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`) which is currently maintained and supported by Microsoft for PHP 5.2.X and 5.3.X.

And I also got the link for downloading these drivers [Linux SQLSRV driver download](http://pecl.php.net/package/sqlsrv) for linux but I could not configure.

If someone has got idea how to configure the **sqlsrv** driver on linux or has some other alternative to retrieve the data from *SQL* server in *UTF-8* format, please share.

Comment: didn't try that myself before, but did you installed the odbc driver required for this extension ? http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28160

Comment: odbc driver installation is already done, I just can't figure out how to install sqlsrv driver, even can't figure out whether it can be installed on linux

Comment: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/sqlsrv.requirements.php says it's a windows-only extension. Where did you read otherwise?

Comment: Yeah, I even read those comments but I found the package for linux too.http://pecl.php.net/package/sqlsrv

Comment: I see no indication that the driver at pecl.php.net/package/sqlsrv  is for linux. It's the same windows-only package you can download from codeplex.

Comment: Thanks for your concern @VolkerK. I thought the file provided for download has extension capable to install on linux. Anyway, what can be the alternative then ?

Comment: Have you looked at FreeTDS?

Comment: FreeTDS even didn't support UTF-8

Comment: @hsuk have you resolved that problem? I have same disaster with `NVARCHAR `

Answer (score 2):

Here's a wiki post from the Microsoft Community

https://github.com/Microsoft/msphpsql/wiki/Install-pdo_sqlsrv-for-PHP-7.0-on-Debian

I think the easiest route would be the php-pear route

```
# (1) Install PDO driver from pecl
apt-get install unixodbc-dev php7.0-dev php-pear
pecl install pdo_sqlsrv-4.0.5
echo -e "; priority=20\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so" > /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
phpenmod -v 7.0 pdo_sqlsrv
```

Comment: I haven't tested this but there's no harm in trying it out for yourself :)

Answer (score 1):

I Googled a bit more after I read this and I may have found the answer.  On Debian:

```
# apt-get install freetds-common freetds-bin unixodbc php5-mssql
```

That will install everything PHP needs for Free TDS and allows me to connect using the sqlsrv driver.

Answer (score 1):

Other UTF-8 compatible solution dblib:

1. You install freetds and use php-mssql driver with PDO.
2. Change encoding in /etc/freetds.conf
3. Change charset and date format in /etc/locales.conf

I did it back in 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Please change:

```
echo -e "; priority=20\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so" > /etc/php/7.0/mods-   available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
```

to:

```
echo -e "; priority=20\nextension=pdo_sqlsrv.so" > /etc/php/7.0/mods-available/pdo_sqlsrv.ini
```