# Cant connect to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio through PHP

Tags: php, sql-server

I am relatively new to both PHP and SQL and I am in the process of developing a PHP application to run on a work server. I have created a test page using code from php.net to literally test the connection and I keep getting the following **error**:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()
```

My code is

```
<?php
$server = 'myserver\SQLEXPRESS';

$link = mssql_connect($server, 'username', 'password');

if (!$link) {  
die('Something went wrong while connecting to MSSQL');  
}  
?>
```

Obviously I cant proceed with the project until I can establish the connection, is there anything I could be missing or doing wrong?

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: You don't "connect to SSMS", you "connect to SQL Server" (just as SSMS does).

Comment: Did you try with $link = mysqli_connect($server, 'username', 'password');

Comment: What is your php version? Your undefined function means that it doesn't regcognize the command. Or have you installed the driver of mssql?

Comment: My php version is 5.4.24 thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update, after looking at other threads on this site I have found a solution! The answer to the following question solved it for me:

[Trying to install MSSQL drivers with EasyPHP 12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631988/trying-to-install-mssql-drivers-with-easyphp-12)

Thank you all very much for your help and thank you to the person responsible for the original answer!

Answer (score 0):

There can be number of reasons. Most probably is that you use PHP 5.3+ and mssql functions are not supported since this version. You should use PDO or SQLSRV driver from Microsoft. Try to run `phpinfo()` to see which drivers are supported on your installation.

Answer (score 0):

i have forgotten from where i got this answer, but it has been more than 1 year.

```
1. First search for `;extension=php_mssql.dll` in php.ini file and remove semicolon `;`.
2. Copy `ntwdblib.dll` from php directory to windows root directory, sometimes it dosen't
work so you will have to copy it in system32 directory.
3. Copy `php_mssql.dll` from php directory to windows root directory, again sometimes it 
dosen't work so you will have to copy it in system32 directory.
4. Search or download `msvcr71.dll` and copy it in windows system32 directory.
5. Restart apache web server.
```

This works for me. Please try and let me know the result.

Comment: Just another question which I maybe should have asked initially. I am using PHPmyadmin to host the PHP site, but the server that has the sql server on is a different server, which one needs the php extensions etc?

Comment: I don't know for sure but the one on which the web server is installed. If necessary you can copy files on both servers.

Comment: which php.ini file? there are two within the easyphp folder one in binaries\conf files and one in php\php_runningversion. I cannot locate `;extension=php_mssql.dll on either. Thanks for the help

Comment: use `phpinfo()` function of php to view configuration of php. Search for string "_Configuration File (php.ini) Path_" or "_Loaded Configuration File_". This will show you the location of _php.ini_ file, if you cannot loacate `;extension=php_mssql.dll` then just add the line `extension=php_mssql.dll` with other extensions. And restart the web server after making changes.