# Connecting to a MS SQL server from a different machine running PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a server running MSSQL. 
Then I have another server running the usual LAMP (php) stack. 
Is there any easy way to connrect to the MSSQL server from the linux server?

(I don't have details on what version of sql server its using at the moment)

thanks

Comment: did you tried `$link = mssql_connect($server, 'user', 'pass');`?

Comment: And your MSSQL server must be set to access connections from remote servers.

Comment: What version of php do u have?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install ODBC for LINUX and FreeDTS.
FreeTDS is a set of libraries for Unix and Linux that allows your programs to natively talk to Microsoft SQL Server and Sybase databases. 
http://www.freetds.org/

Try to use 'search' on stackoverflow.com 
[PHP MS SQL Unix Driver - Microsoft or FreeTDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684782/php-ms-sql-unix-driver-microsoft-or-freetds)

Answer (score 0):

To connect to an MSSQL server from a PHP script you can run the mssql_connect() [*(doc)*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php) function. The parameters you'll need for a remote server are, in order:

1. The hostname of the server you are connecting to.
2. The username with which you wish to connect.
3. The password for that username.

All of these parameters are strings. You can then run queries using the mssql_query() [*(doc)*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php) function.

For more information about connecting to MSSQL servers from PHP scripts take a look at [the PHP documentation on MSSQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php), and [the list of PHP function for MSSQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mssql.php).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the extension mssql.so. Go to php.ini and comment out the extension. As @k102 suggested try connecting using

```
mssql_connect (string $servername , string $username,  string $password )
```

For syntax check the link http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-connect.php