# Want to connect PHP5 to MS SQL SERVER 2005 in linux

Tags: php, sql-server, linux

I want to connect mssql server using php code on linux operating system. i want to use mssql_connect() .please help me. my code is

```
$server='x.x.x.x\SQLEXPRESS';
$link = mssql_connect($server, 'username', 'password');
if (!$link)
{
  die("Couldn't connect to SQL Server on $server. Error: " . mssql_get_last_message());
}
else
{
  echo "Connected!";
}
```

it show error "Unable to connect to server: x.x.x.x\SQLEXPRESS"

Comment: So what is the actual problem. If configured correctly php shouldn't have any problems connecting to mssql server. Could you explain what problems or error messages you encounter.

Comment: i have modified my question. please help me

Comment: @infinity: Can you be a bit more specific about your problem please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP MS SQL Unix Driver - Microsoft or FreeTDS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684782/php-ms-sql-unix-driver-microsoft-or-freetds)

Comment: mssql, free tds all are enable

Comment: feel tired, no solution.

Answer (score 1):

For me, this worked under debian lenny:

```
apt-get install libsybdb5 freetds-common php5-sybase
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

I found the solution here: http://docs.moodle.org/20/en/Installing_MSSQL_for_PHP