# mssql_connect on centos 6.2 not working

Tags: php, sql-server, centos, freetds

Info:

- server: centos 6.2
- PHP Version 5.3.3

had install: freetds; ODBC; php_mssql
selinux was disable
mssql.so was enable in php.ini
I install follow instructions: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6636
everything work fine,the odbc_connect success but I cannot use mssql_connect or mssql_* (like unknown fun mssql).

can everyone help me to fix it?

Comment: The installation instructions you have followed are from Feb 14, 2003. Did you also take the centos version that was used that time? Or why are you sure that it must work?

Answer (score 2):

The installation instruction you are using looks pretty outdated for your Centos version.

Instead I suggest you revert the installation you've done so fare completely and then just install the pacakges from the package manager:

```
yum install php-odbc php-mssql
```

A more recent installation instruction can be found here:

- [Install MSSql on Centos 6](http://thebitstream.co.uk/helpful-stuff/install-mssql-on-centos-6) (ca. September 2011)

Hope this helps. And as long as ODBC functions are working, you can use ODBC functions to connect to the mssql server. No need to actually to use the `mssql_*` functions as they do not work with your setup for some reason.

Comment: I found a solution: {First install FreeTDS and then configure PHP with --with-mssql=/prefix/used/for/freetds} in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684782/php-ms-sql-unix-driver-microsoft-or-freetds?rq=1
How about i do this?

Comment: Remi has a php-mssql package, so I do not think you actually need to compile PHP your own. See http://rpms.famillecollet.com/

Answer (score 0):

you can check following article step by step.
any query let me know
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/39838.troubleshooting-mssql-server-for-linux.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> Restarting Apache Server
>
> /etc/init.d/httpd restart
>
> http://howtogetitworking.com/2008/02/26/how-to-install-mssql-extension-for-php-on-unix/